# Will a VHDL compiler optimise this away or not?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, compiler-optimization, xilinx

If I have an operation like the one below that depends on a constant parameter will the compiler see that this if statement will always be the first case and therefore optimise it away or not?

```
entity Thing is 
  generic(
    constant N : integer := 32;
    constant M : integer := 24
);

...

architecture behaviour of Thing is

...

  process(clk)
  begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then

      ...

      if N > M then
        -- do a thing
      else
        -- do a different thing
      end if;

    ...
    end if;
  end process;
end behaviour;
```

Comment: In synthesis, almost certainly yes. There are a variety of synthesis attributes you can attach to signals to try and stop this happening. What are you *really* asking here?

Comment: This depends on the compiler. Some tools can be configured so that they optimize the design more or less. By default most of them would not implement the `else` when the condition is constant expect if you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Generics are elaboration time supplied values. You're not inferring the absence or presence of code but whether or not the code is reached during simulation. There may be implementation dependent (non-portable) link time optimization for dead code removal. The savings in simulation execution time might be minimal and code size savings depending on 'do a different thing' subprogram call exclusivity and size. Brian's comment question is valid. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've a chunk of code that needs to be slightly different depending on which of N or M is larger. Basically, in one case I use shift_left(abs(N-M)) in the other shift_right(abs(N-M)). I can either have 2 versions of the code, one for if M>N and another for if N>M or I can have this if statement. I was wanting to know if the if statement would increase resource usage or decrease the maximum operatable clock rate of the design.

Comment: *I decided to use the unsigned datatype instead to preserve compatibility of my designs between different versions and platforms as the fixed_pkg doesn't seem to be standard yet so I'm going to close the issue.* fixed_pkg is part of IEEE Std 1076-2008. Most recent tool implementations (versions) support it when complying with that revision. fixed_pkg has been in use since 2003 and may be available in -1993 compatible modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any synthesis tool that I have used, any constants (including `generics`) get propagated through the design in order to produce the simplest possible output. This is good for performance in general.